# How can I replace categorical values with numeric values?

Tags: r, replace, subset, numeric, categorical-data

How can I replace categorical values with numeric values in R? To be more specific, I have the variable `trstep` which describes the degree of trust in the EU parliament. This variable is recoded as follows:

```
 0= No trust at all
 1=1 
 2=2
 3=3
 4=4
 5=5 
 6=6 
 7=7 
 8=8 
 9=9 
 10= Complete trust
```

This variable has over 40000 observations which is why I can not work with some codes easily. I would like to replace "No trust at all" to 0 and "Complete trust" to 10 as well as exclude missing values. I would welcome your help!

Answer (score 3):

If your dataframe is called `df` you can try :

```
#Convert `trstep` to character
df$trstep <- as.character(df$trstep)
#Change "No trust at all" to 0
df$trstep[df$trstep == "No trust at all"] <- 0
#Change "Complete trust" to 10
df$trstep[df$trstep == "Complete trust"] <- 10
#Remove NA values
df <- df[!is.na(df$trstep), ]
#If needed convert  trstep to numeric. 
#df$trstep <- as.numeric(df$trstep)
```

Comment: "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors", This is the error message, which I get after running the codes today again. Could you help me to solve this problem please?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to convert to factor and then to integer. Since factors are coded internally as consecutive integers starting at 1, subtract 1 to get integers in the range `0:10`.

```
trstep <- factor(trstep, levels = levels)
as.integer(trstep) - 1
# [1]  2  2  9  1  5 10  4  3  5  8  9 10  4  2 10  8  8  8  2  7  9  6  9  8  2
#[26]  3  0 10  6  4
```

**Test data**

```
set.seed(123)
levels <- c("No trust at all", 1:9, "Complete trust")
trstep <- sample(levels, 30, TRUE)
```